# Graphical programs ran via WSL2 on Windows 11 sometimes open outside of monitor and I can't move them back

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Sometimes when I run Chrome, Cypress Test Runner, Firefox etc from inside my Linux distro running in WSL2 on my Windows 11 machine they stop opening on the visible desktop and I don't seem to be able to move them back onto the monitor.

I can see the icon in the taskbar but I can't do anything with it other than close it.

The only way to fix it seems to be by rebooting my machine, which is slightly impractical.

Comment: Any feedback on whether or not my answer helped?  Also, what does `xrandr` show?  Does it match your Windows desktop resolution?

Comment: It's not happened again for me to try the fix. 

If I run `xrandr` I can see my three monitors connected, `XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm` `XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+1001+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm` and `XWAYLAND2 connected 1920x1080+1920+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm`

Comment: Yep, I'm seeing this too - it seems after a few chrome windows are launched (via chromedriver/behave), no further windows work. This link has additional info: https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/discussions/370 ., such as you can resolve by rebooting WSL with `wsl.exe --shutdown`, but again, not ideal...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's happening, but as an alternative to rebooting, you can try moving the window back on screen via either [`xdotool` or `wmctrl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029302/11810933).

For example, with `xdotool`, first install it via:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then do something like:

```
xdotool search --pid $(pgrep -xo xterm) --class '.' windowmove 100 100
```

Note that the `-class '.'` is just to work around an [issue](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/14).

There are other ways to search for the proper window as well.  See the man page for details.

You can get more info on the classes and ids of all of the X windows using `xlsclients -l`.